# How to add data from a text file to ComboBox in JavaFX?

Tags: file, text, javafx, combobox

I create a ComboBox in Scene Builder and I want to populate him with data from a text file (eg. Text.txt):

public class ToDoListController implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<?> eventsSelector;
```

How to do this?

Thank you very much!

Two solutions:
1.

@FXML
    private ComboBox eventsSelector;

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
      List<String> myList;
      try {
        myList = Files.lines(Paths.get("path of my text file")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        eventsSelector.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(myList));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Don t find file");
    }
```

}
2.

```
    //Read items from txt File
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
        FileReader("path of my text file"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            //Add Item
            eventsSelector.getItems().add(line);

            sb.append(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Don t find file");

    }
```

Comment: Does my answer work for your?? Or do you need sth else?

Comment: Thanks! I will try tomorow. I keeping you in touch!

Comment: That would be nice. Write me if you have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to add content from a `.txt` file the items in the `ComboBox` are `String`s so you can change to this :

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> eventsSelector;
```

Then you need a list of the elements that you want to add to the `ComboBox<String>`, then you can add them simply by:

```
List<String> myList = Files.lines(path).collect(Collectors.toList());
comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(myList));
```

Comment: I also prefer using Java8 streams but I wrote as simply as it can, to be more more understanding. But if @Daniel is familiar with streams yeah this is the better way.

Comment: This maybe can help you understanding that line of code: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code for you, this should work for you:

```
public class YourController {
//Combobox
@FXML
ComboBox<String> combobx;

//Initialize FXML
@FXML
public void initialize() throws IOException {
    //Read items from txt File
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/items.txt"));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            //Add Item
            combobx.getItems().add(line);

            sb.append(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }

    //Default Selection first item
    combobx.getSelectionModel().select(0);
}
}
```

The txt file must be in this case in the root directory of your project.